# Calling Select inside of List<> extended method in C#

Tags: c#, select, ienumerable

Just wondering why a Select call won't execute if it's called inside of an extended method?
Or is it maybe that I'm thinking Select does one thing, while it's purpose is for something different?

Code Example:

```
var someList = new List<SomeObject>();
int triggerOn = 5;
/* list gets populated*/
someList.MutateList(triggerOn, "Add something", true);
```

MutateList method declaration:

```
    public static class ListExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SomeObject> MutateList(this IEnumerable<SomeObject> objects, int triggerOn, string attachment, bool shouldSkip = false)
        {
            return objects.Select(obj =>
            {
                if (obj.ID == triggerOn)
                {
                    if (shouldSkip) shouldSkip = false;
                    else obj.Name += $" {attachment}";
                }
                return obj;
            });
        }
     }
```

The solution without Select works. I'm just doing a foreach instead.

I know that the Select method has a summary saying: "Projects each element of a sequence into a new form." But if that were true, then wouldn't my code example be showing errors?

Solution that I used (Inside of the MutateList method):

```
        foreach(SomeObject obj in objects)
        {
            if (obj.ID == triggerOn)
            {
                if (shouldSkip) shouldSkip = false;
                else obj.Name += $" {attachment}";
            }
        });
        return objects;
```

Comment: Please note `Select` returns a new enumerable. It does not modify the enumerable it operates on.

Comment: "Select call won't execute " - How did you check it wasn't executed?

Comment: "The solution without Select works." - which solution without Select? Such a solution is not shown.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I was being slightly petty and showing where the list _is_ mutated (grated it's the items in the list not the list itself)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I updated the question with the solution. And I tested it by adding a breakpoint inside of the Select.

Comment: In this case, I think it's a bad idea to modify the existing objects. I would create new objects to return. If you want to reuse the same instances, don't use linq, but just a foreach loop.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Thanks for the feedback! Well I thought since I'm just mutating an argument, then it would be a waste to create a new object just for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` uses *deferred execution*, meaning that it does not actually execute until you try to *iterate* over the results, with a `ForEach`, or using Linq methods that require the actual results like `ToList` or `Sum`.

Also, it *returns an iterator*, it does not run on the items in-place, but you're not capturing the return value in your calling code.

For those reasons - I would recommend *not* using `Select` to mutate the object in the list. You're just wrapping a `ForEach` call in a less clean way. I would just use `ForEach` within the method.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I thought it would be a good idea to use it like this. So for instance if later on someone wants to do the same thing, but for a different id, they can just attach the same call. Like: `someList.MutateList(triggerOn, "Add something", true).MutateList(triggerOnSomethingElse "Add", true)`.

Comment: You can still do that with a `foreach` by returning `objects`

Comment: I'll go with that. Thank you.